# Why does a date conversion return different timestamps?

Tags: java, date, calendar, unix-timestamp

I am converting a GregorianCalendar instance to a Date to get a unix timestamp.

But I was wondering why the same date returns different Unix timestamps each time.

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(2018, 0, 1, 0,0,0);
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
Date date = calendar.getTime();

System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
System.out.println(date.getTime());
```

The date itself is correct and is always the same, `"2018/01/01 00:00:00"`. But why is the unix timestamp different each time? For example, these are the values after 5 executions.

```
1514761200624
1514761200618
1514761200797
1514761200209
1514761200132
```

Comment: the last 3-digits of the timestamp represent milliseconds. You are setting till seconds only. That's why you are seeing this difference.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed, as your results show, and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `Instant`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are instantiating everything within a loop in your example?

If so, you are not setting the milliseconds difference, so they change (however slightly) in each iteration of the loop.

To avoid this, you could either set the milliseconds, or do the instantiation outside of the loop:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(2018, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
     Date date = calendar.getTime();
     System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
     System.out.println(date.getTime());
}
```

This will produce:

> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 1514764800128
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 1514764800128
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 1514764800128
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 1514764800128
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 2018/01/01 00:00:00
>
> 1514764800128

Answer (score 5):

When you create a new calendar it contains current date and time. After that you update all fields EXCEPT milliseconds. As you can see only last 3 numbers differs in all your outputs, it is milliseconds of the execution time.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels");
    ZonedDateTime start2018 = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JANUARY, 1).atStartOfDay(zone);
    Instant asInstant = start2018.toInstant();
    System.out.println(asInstant.toEpochMilli());
```

This consistently gives the following output:

> 1514761200000

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be Europe/Brussels.

To format for output:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(start2018.format(formatter));
```

> 2018/01/01 00:00:00

The date and time classes that you were using — `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar` and `Date` — are all poorly designed and long outdated. `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is notoriously troublesome, but in this case it was the poor design of `Calendar` that gave you unexpected results. The other answers have already explained how, there is no need for me to repeat. Instead of the old classes I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

In timestamp, last 3-digit represents the milliseconds. Here you are explicitly setting the date and time but not the milliseconds. That's why you are facing this. To avoid this you can add this to your code:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```